# phpdotenv not working with me and showing blank page

Tags: php, environment-variables

I'm new in vlucas/phpdotenv and I want to test it before using it in my project so I made a test folder and installed vlucas/phpdotenv in it and this is my code page:

```
<?php

require_once realpath(__DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php");

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv =  Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);

$dotenv->load();

$app_name = getenv("APP_NAME");

echo $app_name;

?>
```

**and there is no output** I only get a blank page and when I make `var_dump($app_name);` I get an error

```
bool(false)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `getenv` returns false when the environment variable does not exist, so `bool(false)` is not an error, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php.  I'm not familiar with Dotenv, but the APP_NAME environment variable does not exist or is not loaded.

Comment: Is your .env file in the right path?

Comment: the APP_NAME is correct  and .env file is in the right path

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who finds this and wonders why theres is not working. `getenv` was marked unsafe a while back, you must instantiate `dotenv` in your script with `Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable` to be able to use `getenv()` rather than `$_ENV`, although it is not advised to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, but I solved it with the following code.

```
<?php
  require './vendor/autoload.php';
  Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__)->load();
  $stripeSecretKey = $_ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'];
  echo $stripeSecretKey;
```

`.env` file content

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_1234567890123456
```

Answer (score 0):

I Used an old version From Node.js and an old version from vlucas/phpdotenv and it works!